# Own implementation of C++ std::string_view

Tags: c++, strings, c++11

In order to improve my C++ skills I started doing some toy projects, one of them being my own std::string_view implementation. This was my first time implementing a std library. I'm pasting the code inline, but you can check it out at https://github.com/david89/cpp-library/tree/master/types if you want (there are some tests there as well).

Few things to take into consideration:

- Kept track of includes manually, maybe there are some unnecessary includes or missing ones. Next time I'll integrate iwyu into my workflow.
- The interface is based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view.
- I tried to keep it C++11 compatible. Coding this in C++17 felt weird as the library is already there.

Any feedback will be appreciated, however I have some specific areas I would like to get feedback on:

- Any suggestions on adding constexpr support for all remaining operations? For example, std::reverse_iterator is not constexpr in C++11. I guess I could code my own version, but not sure if there is something easier I can do.
- There are some non-member friend functions which bothers me a little bit. My understanding is that we need them to be non-member because of comparisons like const char* vs string_view, where only the right hand side can be implicitly casted into a string_view. However, if I declare them outside the class as regular non-friend functions, gtest complains about it. Not very sure why they have to be friend functions if they don't rely on protected/private implementation aspects of the class.
- I think the answer to this is that I should write my own benchmarks and measure it myself, but any idea or intuition on how efficient char_traits operations are? For example, I'm relying on std::char_traits::compare, but maybe using memcmp may be better here.

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_STRING_VIEW
#define LIBRARY_STRING_VIEW

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

namespace david {

// NOTE: using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view as a
// guide.
template <class CharT, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>>
class basic_string_view {
 public:
  // Types.
  using traits_type = Traits;
  using value_type = CharT;
  using pointer = CharT*;
  using const_pointer = const CharT*;
  using reference = CharT&;
  using const_reference = const CharT&;
  using const_iterator = const CharT*;
  using iterator = const_iterator;
  using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
  using reverse_iterator = const_reverse_iterator;
  using size_type = size_t;
  using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
  static constexpr size_type npos = size_type(-1);

  // Construction.
  constexpr basic_string_view() noexcept : data_(nullptr), len_(0) {}
  constexpr basic_string_view(const basic_string_view& other) noexcept =
      default;
  constexpr basic_string_view(const_pointer str)
      : data_(str), len_(internal_strlen(str)) {}
  constexpr basic_string_view(const_pointer str, size_type len)
      : data_(str), len_(len) {}
  basic_string_view(const std::string& str)
      : data_(str.data()), len_(str.size()) {}

  // Assignment.
  basic_string_view& operator=(const basic_string_view&) noexcept = default;

  // Iterator support.
  constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return data_; }
  constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return begin(); }
  constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return data_ + len_; }
  constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return end(); }
  // TODO: these cannot be marked as constexpr because std::reverse_iterator is
  // not constexpr.
  const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator(end());
  }
  const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept { return rbegin(); }
  const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator(begin());
  }
  const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept { return rend(); }

  // Element access.
  constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const {
    return data_[pos];
  }
  const_reference at(size_type pos) const {
    if (pos > len_) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
    }

    return this->operator[](pos);
  }
  constexpr const_reference front() const { return data_[0]; }
  constexpr const_reference back() const { return data_[len_ - 1]; }
  constexpr const_pointer data() const noexcept { return data_; }

  // Capacity.
  constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return len_; }
  constexpr size_type length() const noexcept { return size(); }
  constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept { return kMaxSize; }
  constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return len_ == 0; }

  // Modifiers.
  void remove_prefix(size_type n) {
    data_ = data_ + n;
    len_ -= n;
  }
  void remove_suffix(size_type n) { len_ -= n; }
  void swap(basic_string_view& s) noexcept {
    basic_string_view other = *this;
    *this = s;
    s = other;
  }

  // Operations.
  // Copies the substring [pos, pos + rcount) to the character string pointed to
  // by dest, where rcount is the smaller of count and size() - pos.
  size_type copy(pointer dest, size_type count, size_type pos = 0) const {
    if (pos > len_) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
    }

    const size_type rcount = std::min(count, len_ - pos);
    traits_type::copy(dest, data_ + pos, rcount);
    return rcount;
  }
  // Returns a view of the substring [pos, pos + rcount), where rcount is the
  // smaller of count and size() - pos.
  basic_string_view substr(size_type pos = 0, size_type count = npos) const {
    if (pos > len_) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
    }

    const size_type rcount = std::min(count, len_ - pos);
    if (rcount > 0) {
      return basic_string_view(data_ + pos, rcount);
    }
    return basic_string_view();
  }
  // Compares two character sequences.
  int compare(basic_string_view s) const noexcept {
    const size_t rlen = std::min(len_, s.len_);
    const int comparison = traits_type::compare(data_, s.data_, rlen);
    if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
    if (len_ == s.len_) return 0;
    return len_ < s.len_ ? -1 : 1;
  }
  // Compare substring(pos1, count1) with s.
  int compare(size_type pos1, size_type count1, basic_string_view s) const {
    return substr(pos1, count1).compare(s);
  }
  // Compare substring(pos1, count1) with s.substring(pos2, count2).
  int compare(size_type pos1, size_type count1, basic_string_view s,
              size_type pos2, size_type count2) const {
    return substr(pos1, count1).compare(s.substr(pos2, count2));
  }
  int compare(const_pointer s) const { return compare(basic_string_view(s)); }
  int compare(size_type pos1, size_type count1, const_pointer s) const {
    return substr(pos1, count1).compare(basic_string_view(s));
  }
  int compare(size_type pos1, size_type count1, const_pointer s,
              size_type count2) const {
    return substr(pos1, count1).compare(basic_string_view(s, count2));
  }
  bool starts_with(basic_string_view s) const noexcept {
    return len_ >= s.len_ && substr(0, s.len_) == s;
  }
  bool starts_with(value_type c) const noexcept {
    return !empty() && traits_type::eq(front(), c);
  }
  bool starts_with(const_pointer s) const {
    return starts_with(basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>(s));
  }
  bool ends_with(basic_string_view s) const noexcept {
    return len_ >= s.len_ && substr(len_ - s.len_, npos) == s;
  }
  bool ends_with(value_type c) const noexcept {
    return !empty() && traits_type::eq(back(), c);
  }
  bool ends_with(const_pointer s) const {
    return ends_with(basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>(s));
  }
  size_type find(basic_string_view s, size_type pos = 0) const noexcept {
    if (empty() && s.empty() && pos == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (pos > len_ || s.len_ > (len_ - pos)) {
      return npos;
    }
    while (pos + s.len_ <= len_) {
      if (traits_type::compare(data_ + pos, s.data_, s.len_) == 0) {
        return pos;
      }

      pos++;
    }

    return npos;
  }
  size_type find(value_type c, size_type pos = 0) const noexcept {
    return find(basic_string_view(&c, 1), pos);
  }
  size_type find(const_pointer s, size_type pos, size_type n) const {
    return find(basic_string_view(s, n), pos);
  }
  size_type find(const_pointer s, size_type pos = 0) const {
    return find(basic_string_view(s), pos);
  }
  size_type rfind(basic_string_view s, size_type pos = npos) const noexcept {
    if (s.empty()) {
      return std::min(pos, len_);
    }
    if (s.len_ > len_) {
      return npos;
    }
    pos = std::min(pos, len_ - s.len_);
    while (pos != npos) {
      if (traits_type::compare(data_ + pos, s.data_, s.len_) == 0) {
        return pos;
      }

      pos--;
    }

    return npos;
  }
  size_type rfind(value_type c, size_type pos = npos) const noexcept {
    return rfind(basic_string_view(&c, 1), pos);
  }
  size_type rfind(const_pointer s, size_type pos, size_type n) const {
    return rfind(basic_string_view(s, n), pos);
  }
  size_type rfind(const_pointer s, size_type pos = npos) const {
    return rfind(basic_string_view(s), pos);
  }
  size_type find_first_of(basic_string_view s,
                          size_type pos = 0) const noexcept {
    while (pos < len_) {
      if (traits_type::find(s.data_, s.len_, data_[pos]) != nullptr) {
        return pos;
      }

      pos++;
    }

    return npos;
  }
  size_type find_first_of(value_type c, size_type pos = 0) const noexcept {
    return find_first_of(basic_string_view(&c, 1), pos);
  }
  size_type find_first_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos, size_type n) const {
    return find_first_of(basic_string_view(s, n), pos);
  }
  size_type find_first_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos = 0) const {
    return find_first_of(basic_string_view(s), pos);
  }
  size_type find_last_of(basic_string_view s,
                         size_type pos = npos) const noexcept {
    if (empty()) {
      return npos;
    }

    pos = std::min(pos, len_ - 1);
    while (pos != npos) {
      if (traits_type::find(s.data_, s.len_, data_[pos]) != nullptr) {
        return pos;
      }

      pos--;
    }

    return npos;
  }
  size_type find_last_of(value_type c, size_type pos = npos) const noexcept {
    return find_last_of(basic_string_view(&c, 1), pos);
  }
  size_type find_last_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos, size_type n) const {
    return find_last_of(basic_string_view(s, n), pos);
  }
  size_type find_last_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos = npos) const {
    return find_last_of(basic_string_view(s), pos);
  }
  size_type find_first_not_of(basic_string_view s,
                              size_type pos = 0) const noexcept {
    while (pos < len_) {
      if (traits_type::find(s.data_, s.len_, data_[pos]) == nullptr) {
        return pos;
      }

      pos++;
    }

    return npos;
  }
  size_type find_first_not_of(value_type c, size_type pos = 0) const noexcept {
    return find_first_not_of(basic_string_view(&c, 1), pos);
  }
  size_type find_first_not_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos,
                              size_type n) const {
    return find_first_not_of(basic_string_view(s, n), pos);
  }
  size_type find_first_not_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos = 0) const {
    return find_first_not_of(basic_string_view(s), pos);
  }
  size_type find_last_not_of(basic_string_view s,
                             size_type pos = npos) const noexcept {
    if (empty()) {
      return npos;
    }

    pos = std::min(pos, len_ - 1);
    while (pos != npos) {
      if (traits_type::find(s.data_, s.len_, data_[pos]) == nullptr) {
        return pos;
      }

      pos--;
    }

    return npos;
  }
  size_type find_last_not_of(value_type c,
                             size_type pos = npos) const noexcept {
    return find_last_not_of(basic_string_view(&c, 1), pos);
  }
  size_type find_last_not_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos,
                             size_type n) const {
    return find_last_not_of(basic_string_view(s, n), pos);
  }
  size_type find_last_not_of(const_pointer s, size_type pos = npos) const {
    return find_last_not_of(basic_string_view(s), pos);
  }

  // We need these to be friend non-member functions because we want to compare
  // operands with different types (for example string_view vs const char*).
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/3850120
  friend inline bool operator==(basic_string_view a,
                                basic_string_view b) noexcept {
    return a.compare(b) == 0;
  }
  friend inline bool operator!=(basic_string_view a,
                                basic_string_view b) noexcept {
    return a.compare(b) != 0;
  }

  friend inline bool operator<(basic_string_view a,
                               basic_string_view b) noexcept {
    return a.compare(b) < 0;
  }

  friend inline bool operator>(basic_string_view a,
                               basic_string_view b) noexcept {
    return a.compare(b) > 0;
  }

  friend inline bool operator<=(basic_string_view a,
                                basic_string_view b) noexcept {
    return a.compare(b) <= 0;
  }

  friend inline bool operator>=(basic_string_view a,
                                basic_string_view b) noexcept {
    return a.compare(b) >= 0;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, basic_string_view s) {
    std::ostream::sentry sentry{os};
    if (!sentry) return os;

    // Ideas from:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/39653508

    size_t padding = 0;
    char filler = os.fill();
    if (s.size() < os.width()) {
      padding = os.width() - s.size();
    }

    bool align_left = os.flags() & std::ios_base::left;
    if (padding > 0 && !align_left) {
      while (padding--) os.put(filler);
    }
    os.write(s.data(), s.size());
    if (padding > 0 && align_left) {
      while (padding--) os.put(filler);
    }

    os.width(0);
    return os;
  }

 private:
  constexpr static size_type internal_strlen(const_pointer str) {
    return str ? traits_type::length(str) : 0;
  }

  static constexpr size_type kMaxSize = std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
  const_pointer data_;
  size_type len_;
};

template <class CharT, class Traits>
constexpr typename basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>::size_type
    basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>::npos;

template <class CharT, class Traits>
constexpr typename basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>::size_type
    basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>::kMaxSize;

using string_view = basic_string_view<char>;
using u16string_view = basic_string_view<char16_t>;
using u32string_view = basic_string_view<char32_t>;
using wstring_view = basic_string_view<wchar_t>;

string_view operator"" _sv(const char* str, std::size_t len) noexcept {
  return string_view(str, len);
}
u16string_view operator"" _sv(const char16_t* str, std::size_t len) noexcept {
  return u16string_view(str, len);
}
u32string_view operator"" _sv(const char32_t* str, std::size_t len) noexcept {
  return u32string_view(str, len);
}
wstring_view operator"" _sv(const wchar_t* str, std::size_t len) noexcept {
  return wstring_view(str, len);
}

}  // namespace david

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<david::string_view> {
  size_t operator()(david::string_view s) const {
    // Extracted from
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411888
    return std::_Hash_impl::hash(s.data(), s.length());
  }
};
}  // namespace std

#endif  // LIBRARY_STRING_VIEW
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: "Not very sure why they have to be friend functions" -- there is a subtle difference with respect to name lookup and overload resolution. Defined outside of the class, the operators are template functions, and subject to template argument deduction. So operator==(sv, sv) will only be viable if both arguments are exactly string_views. Defined as friends inside the class, the operators are not template functions, so will be found by ADL when looking up operator==(const char*, sv), and not excluded by TAD. i.e. friend defined inside == implicit conversions allowed.

Comment: Technically, the performance of char_traits isn't guaranteed, but it'd be surprising if it weren't memcmp or better on any given implementation, and should anyone define their own traits, it'd be surprising if they weren't honored. libstdc++ uses memcmp: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L347